# What do I do after I make the chandelier fall?

Tags: ico

I've just gotten past the crane sequence and I'm now in a two-story chamber where I can climb around in the rafters. I hopped on the chandelier and broke it. Now part of the chandelier is on the bottom floor with two lit candles.

I can light my trusty stick on fire with the candles, which I would assume is important to progress. But I can't find anything else to light on fire, nor any dark places to light up within range of the torch's duration.

I saw in the chandelier crash cutscene that the support of the broken bridge is weakened. I assume that I must make the bridge crash, so I can get down to the far first-floor door that Yorda must open. But nothing I do has any effect on the support. I've tried to light it on fire to no avail. I've tried jumping up and down on the bridge above the support, and at the end where leverage would be greatest, but I don't seem to be massive enough to budge it.

Outside of the far second-floor door is a balcony area. I found the box I can push around to get up on the low pillar, and from there I can get on the high pillar near the rope. Nothing I do has any effect on the rope. I can't get there in time with my stick on fire to try to burn it. I can whack it, which makes it vibrate a little. I can't hang from it. I can't find any way to get up on the roof.

**TL;DR:** What do I do after I make the chandelier fall? Please give gentle nudges at first, with increasingly blatant hints in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go downstairs and bring a bomb from outside with you then use a stick and light the bomb on the suport.

Comment: exact, get a bomb, put it near the pillar and light it up (and run :)

Comment: D'oh. I'm playing on a smallish CRT did not recognize those as bombs, I thought they were just pots like the ones inside. Thanks!